# Add padding between items

Tags: css, reactjs

I use this code to display label and drop down:

```
const exchangeid = {
  display: "inline-block",
};
const exchangeidsearch = {
  display: "inline-block",
  paddingLeft: "10px",
};
```

.......

```
<th className="hand">
  <div style={exchangeid} onClick={sort('pair')}>
    Exchange Id <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sort" />
  </div>
  <div style={exchangeidsearch}>
    Filter
     <select>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</th>
```

How I can space between text `Filter` and select drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to add space between the text 'filter' and the select element? You should probably wrap the filter in `span` (or a `div` or anything more relevant). Then you can add simple `margin-right` to your `span`:

```css
.exchangeid {
  display: inline-block;
}

.exchangeidsearch {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.text {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<th class="hand">
  <div class="exchangeid" onClick={sort('pair')}>
    Exchange Id <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sort" />
  </div>
  <div class="exchangeidsearch">
    <span class="text">Filter</span>
     <select>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</th>
```